# DotNetNuke error ThreadAboutException

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

We am facing some issue in dot net nuke. We have a application hosted in dot net nuke version-5.1.4.3 in production and development. We have a small change to be done, so we are adding a new reference/dll in development version and the application is working properly, but when we are adding the same dll in production copy, we are facing Threading.ThreadAbortException. and since it is dotnet nuke, we are not able to point out where the error is occuring. We have tried to copy the entire production setup to development and tried replacing the dlls, then too in development it is working fine.

The application is VB.NET application, with .net framework 2.0 and sql server -2014. The application is hosted in IIS 7 and the data access layer has been created using MyGeneration.dOOdads.dll in both production and development. The change was to add a new column in table and since we were not able to change the existing dataAccess.dll, we created a new dataaccess.dll and in development it worked fine, but started throwing error in production which has the same configuration as developemnt.

Kindly suggest any further actions that can be done to resolve this issue as soon as possible by adding the new dll.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask